# React with React-Router: RouteHandler component is completely ignored in the output

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working my way through the react-router guides (http://rackt.github.io/react-router/), and have a nice little router set up. But the Route node in the routes variable completely ignores the {Application} handler, and just straight-up renders the Dashboard onto the page, with no control over where it goes. Any ideas?

Here is the code I'm using as my test:

```
var React = require("react"),
    Router = require("react-router"),
    Route = Router.Route,
    DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute,
    RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler, // I can comment this out and nothing breaks

    App = {
        Dashboard: require("./js/components/Dashboard.jsx")
    },

    routes = (
        <Route path="/" handler={Application}>
            <DefaultRoute handler={App.Dashboard} />
        </Route>
    ),

    // This React component is ignored, even though it's set as the handler in the routes object
    Application = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>THIS TITLE IS NEVER ACTUALLY RENDERED</h1>

                    {/* The RouteHandler here is just ignored. I can comment it out, and rendering is identical! */}
                    <RouteHandler />
                </div>
            )
        }
    });

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (RouteHandler) {
    React.render(<RouteHandler/>, document.getElementById("app));
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're referring to `Application` before it it assigned. Try moving the route definition *after* creating your `Application` component.

Comment: That was exactly it. What a rookie mistake!

Comment: ...and that's why it's a common practice to put one var per declaration.